# Pytorch geometric: Having issues with tensor sizes

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, data-science

This is the first time I'm using Pytorch and Pytorch geometric. I'm trying to create a simple Graph Neural Network with Pytorch Geometric. I'm creating a custom dataset by following the Pytorch Geometric documentations and extending the InMemoryDataset. After that I split the dataset into training, validation and test dataset which sizes (3496, 437, 439) respectively. These are the number of graphs in each dataset. Here is my simple Neural Network

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = GCNConv(dataset.num_node_features, 10)
    self.conv2 = GCNConv(10, dataset.num_classes)

def forward(self, data):
    x, edge_index, batch = data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch
    x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
    x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)

    return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

I get this error while training my model, which suggest that there's some issue with my input dimensions. Maybe the reason is behind my batch sizes?

```
RuntimeError: The following operation failed in the TorchScript interpreter.
Traceback of TorchScript (most recent call last):
File "E:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch_scatter\scatter.py", line 22, in scatter_add
        size[dim] = int(index.max()) + 1
    out = torch.zeros(size, dtype=src.dtype, device=src.device)
    return out.scatter_add_(dim, index, src)
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
else:
    return out.scatter_add_(dim, index, src)
RuntimeError: index 13654 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 678
```

The error happens specifically on this line of code in the Neural Network,

```
x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
```

**EDIT: Added more information about edge_index and explained in more detail about the data that I'm using.**

Here are the shapes of the variables that I'm trying to pass

```
x: torch.Size([678, 43])
edge_index: torch.Size([2, 668])
torch.max(edge_index): tensor(541690)
torch.min(edge_index): tensor(1920)
```

I'm using a datalist which contains `Data(x=node_features, edge_index=edge_index, y=labels)` objects. When I'm splitting the dataset into training, validation and test datasets, I get `(3496, 437, 439)` graphs in each dataset respectively. Originally I tried to create one single graph from my dataset, but I'm not sure how it would work with `Dataloader` and minibatches.

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Here's the code that generates the graph from dataframe. I've tried to create an simple graph where there are just some amount of vertices with some amount of edges connecting them. I've probably overlooked something and that's why I have this issue. I've tried to follow the Pytorch geometric documentation when creating this graph ([Pytorch Geometric: Creating your own dataset](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/create_dataset.html))

```
def process(self):
        data_list = []

        grouped = df.groupby('EntityId')
        for id, group in grouped:
            node_features = torch.tensor(group.drop(['Labels'], axis=1).values)
            source_nodes = group.index[1:].values
            target_nodes = group.index[:-1].values
            labels = torch.tensor(group.Labels.values)
            edge_index = torch.tensor([source_nodes, target_nodes])

            data = Data(x=node_features, edge_index=edge_index, y=labels)
            data_list.append(data)

        if self.pre_filter is not None:
            data_list = [data for data in data_list if self.pre_filter(data)]

        if self.pre_transform is not None:
            data_list = [self.pre_transform(data) for data in data_list]

        data, slices = self.collate(data_list)
        torch.save((data, slices), self.processed_paths[0])
```

If someone could help me with the process of creating a graph on any kind of data and using it with GCNConv, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Keeping in mind that scatter_add performs this : https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_add_ ,  I think that the problem comes from your edge_index. Can you edit to display the minimum and maximum values of edge_index as well please ? And can you confirm that you are using graphs with 678 nodes ? That feels kinda weird since graphs often have more edges than vertices (especially if you want to perform convolutions on them)

Comment: @trialNerror I edited my question.

Comment: Okay so the problem definitely comes from your graphs, not from your network. In the GCNConv, at some point `scatter_add`will create a tensor `out` with a dimension of length `edge_index.max()+1`(i.e 541691). Then it will iterate simultaneously over this tensor and `x` (of size [678,43]). So there's an obvious problem in your graph : your edges are indexing vertices that do not exist. I mean, apparently the lowest vertex index is 1920, which is already greater than `x` dimensions. So can you clarity how you build your graph ?

Comment: @trialNerror I added part of the code which generates the graph.

Comment: Can you provide one example panda dataframe (I assume that's what `df` is). Not necessarily your actual data, but some data with the same properties (labels, structure...) so that we finally have some kind of reproducible code ? :)

Comment: @trialNerror Sorry, I can't really share any info on the data. The data it's not important since I have difficulties to create even a simple graph. If someone could help me with the process of creating a graph on any kind of data and using it with GCNConv, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with @trialNerror -- it is a data problem. Your `edge_index` should refer to the data nodes and its `max` should not be that high. Since you don't want to show us the data and ask for "creating a graph on any kind of data ", here it is.

I mostly left your `Net` unchanged. You can play around with the constants stated to match with your data.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv
from torch_geometric.data import Data

num_node_features = 100
num_classes = 2
num_nodes = 678
num_edges = 1500
num_hidden_nodes = 128

x = torch.randn((num_nodes, num_node_features), dtype=torch.float32)
edge_index = torch.randint(low=0, high=num_nodes, size=(2, num_edges), dtype=torch.long)
y = torch.randint(low=0, high=num_classes, size=(num_nodes,), dtype=torch.long)

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, num_hidden_nodes)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(num_hidden_nodes, num_classes)

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)

        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index, y=y)

net = Net()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
for i in range(1000):
    output = net(data)
    loss = F.cross_entropy(output, data.y)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if i % 100 == 0:
        print('Accuracy: ', (torch.argmax(output, dim=1)==data.y).float().mean())
```

Output

```
Accuracy:  tensor(0.5059)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.8702)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.9159)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.9233)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.9336)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.9484)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.9602)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.9676)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.9705)
Accuracy:  tensor(0.9749)
```

(yes we can overfit to random data)

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a data problem, I had the same issue. Be very careful with your edge_index'es in particular. Again I can't suggest improvements without seeing the code but your largest node index is 541k yet your x is only of size 678 x 43?!?

I wonder if you are having an issue with batching. Batching is rather strange in pytorch_geometric. The module will combine all your graphs into "one" graph with the individual graph pieces unconnected. It will construct the appropriate new edge index, do the convolution as "one" graph, then split them up again. I wonder if you are trying to do pytorch geometric's job for it and combining all your data into a batch when that isn't necessary. Check the Batch class in the documentation. Thats the only way to Batch things in pytorch geometric.